# Allowing a user to choose a variable in a formula with an OR conditional

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a formula for a column: it reports true if the record was completed this month or is still uncompleted, false if it was completed earlier than this month.

```
CreatedCompletedFilter =
IF (
    OR (
        MONTH ( [Completed date] ) = MONTH ( TODAY () ),
        [Completed date] = BLANK ()
    ),
    TRUE,
    FALSE
)
```

How do I create a report so that, instead of using MONTH(today()), a user can choose a month to apply to this formula via the report itself? I haven't been able to get a slicer to incorporate the OR aspect of formula.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would use a separate, unrelated Date table and then use

```
MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date]))
```

instead of

```
MONTH(today())
```

However, your DAX expression doesn't look like a calculated column formula. Would be good to share some sample data.